# how to write nested loops that prints the capital letter F using *

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
     if (i < 3 || i == 4) for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
     System.out.print("*");
    if (1 > 2 && 1 < 4 || 1 > 4 && 1 <= 7) for (int k = 1; k <= 2; k++)
     System.out.print("*");
    System.out.print("");
    }
  }
```

---

```
**************
*****
*****
**************
**************
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

i want do like this using (for and if).

Comment: Could you please format your question and put a real piece of code (there are some missing `{`?

Comment: why need nested loops?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. What are you checking, for example, `1 > 2` for?

Answer (score 2):

Because in this example, all horizontal lines have a continuous line of * starting from the far left, you can write the number of stars into an int[].

```
int[] stars = new int[] {14, 5, 5, 14, 14, 5, 5, 5, 5};
for (int currentStars : stars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentStars; i++) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: `for-each` loops does not guarantee the correct order

Comment: @JordiCastilla reference? I am pretty sure the iteration order of an array is perfectly defined, but if I am mistaken, I'll be very happy to learn it and read the source about it.

Comment: @amit after researching i must agree with you, in my former school years teacher always encouraged us to use `for-each` but mentioning sorting was not guarantee... now, after your warn and looking [JLS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) I realized that's not true...

Comment: @james, would be great if you can edit your question to remove my downvote.... my bad...

Comment: @JordiCastilla Editted for you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write F, use a single loop. If you want to write all alphabet you will have to improve the method using some List or array to store letter shapes

Example with loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    int repeat = 5;
    if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 4) repeat = 14;

    for (int c = 0; c < repeat; c++)
        System.out.print("*");
}
```

Example with [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    int repeat = 5;
    if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 4) repeat = 14;

    StringUtils.repeat("*", repeat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a single loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
   if(i=1 || i=4 || i=5)
     System.out.println("**************");
   else
     System.out.println("*****");
}
```

If you want to use nested loops you can do it like that:

```
int rowLength=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
   if(i=1 || i=4 || i=5)
     rowLength=14;
   else
     rowLength=5;
  for (int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++){
      System.out.print("*");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

You don't need loops to do that but I guess this is some kind of school question.